# How to get text width inside textarea? (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textarea, width

Is it possible to get width of text inside a textarea element?

I don't want `$('textarea').val().length` per se, as it doesn't depend on font-size.

I would prefer the **absolute width** of the text inside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's well possible this information is impossible to get hold of.

Workaround idea:

- Create a `span` element with the font size settings of the textarea
- Give the span element the input's value using `.text(value)`
- Measure the span's width

Comment: Nice workaround! I wait for some other ansers before accept it

Comment: @framomo86: If I can remember well, this was Facebook's approach to auto-resize the textarea accordingly to the size of the text. But instead of `span` I guess a `pre` element is better, it would jump lines with `\n` and wouldn't need a `<br>`.

Comment: Does this new span/pre need to be inserted into the page? I'm consistently getting a width of 0

Comment: @JuanCaicedo I think it might be! Give it a `display: none` so it doesn't show. (The dimensions *should* be calculated then.)

Comment: It does :) However I think `visibility:hidden` works better than `display:none` because then it still takes up space. It's good to then use absolute positioning so it doesn't move things around on the page. I followed the CSS in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: Very good advise!